# UITextView from rtf Help !

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextview, rtf

getting text from a .rtf file :

this is what i've got so far...

```
gameInfoTextView.text = [UITextView textNamed:@"mw3InfoText.rtf"];
```

or

```
NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"mw3InfoText.rtf" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    gameInfoTextView.text  = myText;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the file first.

Here is a link explaining how to do it.

[iPhone Developer Blog: How to Read a File](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/how-to-read-a-file-from-your-application-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

An RTF file is not encoded using UTF8 as a plain text file might be.

For example, from the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format

a text element might be marked up like:

```
{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard
This is some {\b bold} text.\par
}
```

You would have to parse the various formatting elements to get to the text "This is some bold text."

I don't believe there is a 1-2 line solution in the SDK for this, but there may be 3rd party solutions.